# How to get text to attribute from current tag only, not from all tags in page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox, attr

I'm trying to get text from  and put automatically to attribute "data-title" witch is use to lightbox. In fact, everything works, Unfortunately, there are several tables on the page, so the attribute gets text from all of them. How to fix, to set text in attribut only from current tabel.

```
var y = $(".tr-caption_2020").text(function());
$(".img_2020").attr("data-title", y);
```

---

```
<table class="tr-caption-container_2020"><tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<a class="img_2020" data-lightbox="stage1" href="pic.png">
<img src="/s400/pic.png" /></a>
</td>
<td class="tr-caption_2020">text text text.</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: Can you show your `html` for `.tr-caption_2020` & `.img_2020` elements?

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case you can do this:

```js
$("[class^=tr-caption_]").each(function(i) {
    var thisLabel = $(this);
    var thisClass = thisLabel.attr('class');
    var thisNumber = thisClass.replace('tr-caption_', '');
    var thisText = thisLabel.text();
    $('.img_'+thisNumber).attr("data-title", thisText);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tr-caption-container_2020">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a class="img_2020" data-lightbox="stage1" href="pic.png">
          <img src="/s400/pic.png" /></a>
      </td>
      <td class="tr-caption_2020">text text text.</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skobaljic/51teovf7/8/).

But I would suggest other way, because you actually use classes as IDs, which is pretty useless - either use IDs or data attributes.

In case you use same classes in your code, than you could simply (and much faster, with clean selectors) [do this](https://jsfiddle.net/skobaljic/51teovf7/17/):

```js
$(".lightbox-img").each(function(i) {
    var thisImg = $(this);
    var thisTitle = $(this).closest('tr').find('.lightbox-caption').text();
    thisImg.attr('data-title', thisTitle);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a class="lightbox-img" data-lightbox="stage1" href="pic.png">
          <img src="/s400/pic.png" /></a>
      </td>
      <td class="lightbox-caption">text text text.</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

For further reading I would suggest [Optimize Selectors](https://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/), where we can find that:

> When possible, avoid selectors that include jQuery extensions. These
> extensions cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by
> the native querySelectorAll() DOM method and, therefore, require the
> use of the Sizzle selector engine provided by jQuery.

Comment: you can/should check it/accept it as an answer for future readers, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet in vanilla JS, hope it helps!

```js
const tableRows = document.querySelectorAll('.tr-caption-container_2020 tr');

tableRows.forEach(tr => {
  const cellWithText = tr.querySelector('.tr-caption_2020');
  const cellText = cellWithText.textContent;
  const imageInCell = tr.querySelector('.img_2020 img');
  imageInCell.setAttribute('data-title', cellText)
});
```

```html
<table class="tr-caption-container_2020">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a class="img_2020" data-lightbox="stage1" href="pic.png">
          <img src="/s400/pic.png" />
        </a>
      </td>
      <td class="tr-caption_2020">text text text.</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```